# How to ensure that UINavigationController has finished animating before poping up another one?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I make a program that push uinavigationcontroller. Once done it pop things back and then do something.

One of the thing it wanna do is wait until it finishes poping up before doing that something.

That's because one of the thing that it may do is to push another viewcontroller.

How should I do so?

```
I already create a category 

-(void)SafelyPushController:(UIViewController *) pushee
{
    AssertMainThread;
    if([self.viewControllers lastObject]!=pushee){
        [self pushViewController:pushee animated:YES];
        while (false);
    }
    else{
        //DLog(@"Dont need to pushview");
    }


    while (false);
    //[self pushViewController:pushee animated:YES];
}
```

To prevent some of the cases.

I need more general solution.

Something like:

If navigationController is still animating, wait till it finish in background and do this block at current thread.

That kind of thing.

Comment: Can't you use the navigationController:didShowViewController:animated: in UINavigationControllerDelegate to check when animation has finished?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use *UINavigationController*'s delegate:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UINavigationControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Set it to an object of a class that conforms to this protocol, which implements this method:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

In this method you'll know when you have finished showing a view controller, thus if it was animated the animation has ended. Notice that if you push multiple view controllers you have to keep track of them.

**Documentation**:

[UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
[UINavigationControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UINavigationControllerDelegate)